# Play flash(flv) file in ImageView android

Tags: android, imageview

How to play Flash(flv) file in android's ImageView?
i need to develop game which plays flv file as background.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you still need a solution, try looking here:
http://www.synesthesia.it/playing-flash-flv-videos-in-android-applications

Answer (score 0):

There is a workaround which will also allow you to play from a local asset resource, please read my answer to this similar question for a full solution:

[Problem to load flv video in webview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6596243/problem-to-load-flv-video-in-webview/6855609#6855609)