# Android streaming FLV video

Tags: javascript, android, streaming, flv

I have a JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">var c = "Mokslas ir gamta"; </script>
<script>type="text/javascript" src="http://tv.delfi.lt/js/embed.js"></script>
<script>var _delfiVideoX = 680;var _delfiVideoY = 385;var _delfiVideoSalt = "ttdGHNTK";_createDelfiVideo();</script>
```

Is it possible to stream that FLV video on android? All I could get was static image with video player controls and that's it.

```
WebView view = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.delfi_vide_wv);
view.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
view.loadData(//script above wrapped in html tags//, "text/html", "utf-8");
```

Any hint would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this will work with your javascript method, but there are some examples on FLV out there.

Check out the following article http://www.synesthesia.it/playing-flash-flv-videos-in-android-applications

Also [Problem to load flv video in webview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6596243/problem-to-load-flv-video-in-webview/6855609#6855609) may be useful