# Play flv video in Android

Tags: android, flash

I want to play flv video in Android mobile.

So I used below link example:

http://www.synesthesia.it/playing-flash-flv-videos-in-android-applications

The flv video is playing in HTC mobile but not in Samsung Galaxy Ace. Both mobile versions are 2.2.

I couldn't test in other mobiles whether it is working or not. I think there is problem in flash player plug ins.

How can I find out what the problem is: why was it playing in HTC mobile but not in Samsung Galaxy Ace? And is any additional code required to play flv videos in all devices?

Comment: can you check for flash player plugins in Galaxy Ace?

Comment: yes it was not installed in Galaxy Ace

Comment: @Ramakrishna  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6596243/problem-to-load-flv-video-in-webview

Comment: @nik already i saw the above link question and tried that one also it shows please install Adobe flash player

Comment: ya its compalsory to install flash. because flv stand by flash video

Comment: is was removed from android market . So how can i install

Answer (score 0, accepted):

though Android 2.2 the Ace comes with no Flash Player, because of the CPU is a ARMv6 and flash is only off ARMv7.

Comment: Ahh sry you're right, its not the speed it was the processor itself. It is an ARMv6 but Flash is only off Armv7. I changed it in my answer.

Comment: Thanks for giving information.is there any alternative please tell me