# How to play flv video links in my android application

Tags: android, hyperlink, flv, streaming-flv-video, flvplayer

I want to play these kinds of flv videos that are on web in my android application

Link :  [Video](http://www.fortunagate.com/adaderana_apps/video_player.php?video=http://derana.lk/content/video/SriGauthamaSambuddha24-15thJune2014.flv)

Link : [Video](http://derana.lk/content/video/SriGauthamaSambuddha24-15thJune2014.flv)

I was able to play youtube videos in a webview.. But failed to play these.. What should i do?

Is there a flv plugin i should load inorder to play these links?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6596243/problem-to-load-flv-video-in-webview

Comment: Try to play/test it on device not on emulator.